# Cigarette simulator - How was the animation done? (Android)

Tags: android, animation

I was looking for information on how to implement an animation to my android application in the most efficient way (without out-of-memory error).

Let's say I have the same animation for smoke as this app does:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apps4you.virtualsmoking

(The smoke effects)
And I made these with png's frame by frame animation in photoshop.
(150 frames);

When I add these to my app (using animation-list), I get a memory error.

I'm wondering how he added this animation without a memory crash error.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many solutions to the problem:
1)Use canvas
2)You can even use GLSurfaceview
3)Use some game engine like Cocos2d-x,libgdx,unity or rajawali

Comment: Thanks for replying, any useful guide for that?

Comment: I think the guy is using a particle system in any game engine to achieve the desired and it can be done easily.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCLa-rgR_MA